# disable display image when running OpenBR ShowFaceDetection from command line

Tags: python, openbr

When I run "OPenBR [ShowFaceDetection](http://openbiometrics.org/doxygen/latest/group__cli.html) algorithm" on a picture, it displays me the picture on the screen with my eyes and face detected. My question: is there a way t ask OpenBR not to display me the picture ?

The command:

```
br -algorithm ShowFaceDetection -enrollAll -enroll  path_to_picture.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use this

```
   br -algorithm FaceDetection -enrollAll -enroll path_to_picture.jpg metadata.csv
```

metadata.csv will contain the information about each face detect in the picture